# Dual of 0-1 integer program

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I have worked with LP & IP with solvers like Gurobi and CPLEX. To play around the processes of encoding some practical problem, I am learning how to construct a dual LP from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program.

However, It seems that this algorithm for LP (continuous variables) does not work for 0-1 integer programming (binary variables).

If the primal 0-1 IP is as follows:

- $n$ **binary** variables $x_1, \cdots, x_n$
- **maximize** $c_1 x_1 +\cdots + c_n x_n $, where
  $c_i$ are all integers.
- $m$ constraints: $a_{j1} x_1 +\cdots + a_{jn} x_n  \leq b_j $, or,
  $a_{j1} x_1 +\cdots + a_{jn} x_n  = b_j $, where all coefficients are
  integers.

How to construct the dual program?

Comment: A MIP has no dual. (At least not in the traditional sense).

Comment: Could you please give some info on non-traditional dual?

Comment: E.g. Guzelsoy, Ralphs, Duality for mixed-integer linear programs

Comment: In a certain sense Lagrangian duality also apples to 0-1 problems.